# Creating Demographic Map based on Block Groups with Custom Data using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I am trying to create a custom demographic map based on block groups that fit the following criteria within a 1 mile radius;

- Population = 8,000
- Median HH Income = 50k or less
- Hispanic Pop = 25% or greater

Is it even possible to select a criteria like this without randomly placing 1 mile radius rings all over the mxd to locate this info?

So far I have created a thematic map using stacked block group layers where the base layer is a graduated color scheme of the income that is less than 50k, then the other two layers for population are dot density. Not quite the look I am going for, but starting at the basic levels for me.

Comment: Why not just use a definition query to only show the block groups that meet your needs (ie >8k pop, >50k $, etc...)    then map those?   Also maybe you use ArcScene and extrude one variable and use graduated colors on the other.

Comment: I think you should include a picture of the thematic map that you have created to help potential answerers visualize the issue(s) that you perceive with it.